# Google App Engine: using users.get_current_user().user_id() as id of NDB entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a web app based on Google App Engine (Webapp2/Python and ndb).
I am using the Google OAuth2 authentication and storing in a custom User Entity of my ndb the googleId I get through users.get_current_user().user_id(). 
Thus this entity has both a id (automatically provided by the ndb) and this property called googleId which is set by me.
I use this user object as common ancestor of the other used data I store in the ndb.

This approach is quite annoying because to avoid multiple ndb queries (one for each request) I have to store in session the id of the currently logged user, its googled id AND verify whether it is different from the currently logged user.

I have therefore thought to use the googleId as the KEY of the ndb entity and use it in the ancestor queries.
Like

```
 mu = MyUser(id = users.get_current_user().user_id())
 mu.put()
```

It works perfectly but I was wondering if there could be any valid reason not to do so (i.e. the googleId may be longer than the maximum size of the ndb id properties, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see your `MyUser` model (and maybe some other code) to be more confident, but, assuming that's all in a pretty normal arrangement, I don't think you'll run into any trouble.

Datastore ids can be pretty long, and the `user_id`, in turn, shouldn't be incredibly big anyway (it's unfortunate that neither limit is rigorously documented, but I personally wouldn't unduly worry about either).